# Maximal unit lengths in 3D with $n$ points.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, coloring, polyhedra

Given $n$ points in 3D space (V), what is the maximal number of unit distance lengths (E) between those points?  Here are a few possibilities.  Some of them are [chromatic spindles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ChromaticSpindles/). 
A collection of these best known configurations has been placed at [Maximal Unit Lengths in 3D](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MaximalUnitLengthsIn3D/).

```
 V --  E -- figure  
 4 --  6 -- tetrahedron  
 5 --  9 -- triangular bipyramid  
 6 -- 12 -- octahedron   
 7 -- 15 -- 8 configurations  
 8 -- 18 -- 26 configurations  
 9 -- 22 -- 5 configurations  
10 -- 27 -- 1 configuration   
11 -- 31 -- 1 configuration      
12 -- 35 -- 1 configuration     
13 -- 39 -- 1 configuration      
14 -- 44 -- 1 configuration   
15 -- 48 -- 4 configurations   
16 -- 52 -- 8+ configurations  
17 -- 57 -- 1+ configuration      
18 -- 62 -- 1+ configuration    
19 -- 66 -- 2+ configurations   
20 -- 71 -- 1+ configuration
```

For 21-39 vertices, {75, 79, 84, 90, 93, 97, 101, 106, 110, 116, 120, 127, 131, 136, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160} unit edges are possible.

The maximal log(unit edges)/log(points) is 1.43392 with 14 points producing 44 unit edges.  The points are {{0,0,0}, {3,0,3}, {3,3,0}, {3,-3,0}, {3,0,-3},{0,3,-3}, {6,0,0}, {2,-1,1}, {-1,2,1}, {-1,-1,-2}, {-1,-1,4}, {-1,-4,1},{-4,-1,1}, {2,-4,4}}/(3 sqrt(2)).  They look like the following:

[image: maximal 3D unit graph]

Which of the above objects can be improved upon, with either more unit edges or a more interesting object with the same number of edges?